# How to open a file in MonoDevelop with spaces in the path?

Tags: arch-linux, whitespace

I have installed MonoDevelop using the instructions [here](http://www.monodevelop.com/download/linux/) on my PC running Arch Linux.

I can successfully launch the MonoDevelop IDE using the command:

```
flatpak run com.xamarin.MonoDevelop
```

I can also open individual files by passing  their path as an argument:

```
flatpak run com.xamarin.MonoDevelop "/home/me/file.cs"
```

However, I **cannot** open files that have a space in their path:

```
flatpak run com.xamarin.MonoDevelop "/home/me/some path/file.cs"
```

The IDE opens but no file is loaded.

What am I doing wrong? The path is wrapped in quotes. How would I go about finding what is preventing the file from being opened?

Comment: can you `strace` it for filesystem related system calls and maybe what is being exec'd ?

Comment: @thrig I tried that but `strace` doesn't play nice with `flatpak`: `write(2, "Creating new namespace failed, l"..., 139Creating new namespace failed, likely because the kernel does not support user namespaces.  bwrap must be installed setuid on such systems.) = 139`

Comment: hmm maybe via sysdig then? that requires a kernel module, though

Comment: Do globs work?`flatpak run com.xamarin.MonoDevelop "/home/me/some*path/file.cs"` Or find? `find "/home/me/some path/" -name "file.cs" -exec flatpak run com.xamarin.MonoDevelop {} \;` Not saying this would be a solution (although it might be a workaround), I'm just thinking that might let us understand where this breaks.

Comment: no solution here but a basic work around is just using the Monodevelop GUI to open a path which contains spaces. At least for me the GUI does work though this can be inconvenient when wanting to open a file, so I remain hopeful this will be fixed

Comment: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1565

Comment: Renaming the project is one way to handle it http://answers.unity.com/answers/261566/view.html